# How to check if URL is public (anti-SSRF)?

Tags: node.js, security, ssrf

I have a form on the site which allows the user to input URL - node.js app will then use `request` module to fetch that URL, analyze the response, and print some data back to the user.

I want to make sure rogue users are unable to input intranet addresses, such as 127.0.0.1, localhost, 192.168.0.1, etc. as it seems like a potential security risk. Is it possible to do without querying the IP of the host twice (First with `dns.lookup` and then with `request module`)?

Comment: Good question (+1) - you might also want to check that the domain contacted in the request is the same one that has just been validated as an attacker could set a very low TTL and then change the lookup once it has passed your validation.